# Extracting values only from the value of excel row recived using xlrd -python

Tags: python, excel, xlrd

This problem is specific wrt using xlrd package in python
I got row of excel which is in form of list but each item is integer value;
type:value
this is not string. The row is save by;

```
import xlrd

book = xlrd.open_workbook('myfile.xls')

sh = book.sheet_by_index(0)

for rx in range(sh2.nrows):

  row = sh.row(rx)
```

so row saved has value;

```
row=[text:u'R', text:u'xyz', text:u'Y', text:u'abc', text:u'lmn', empty:'']
```

This is a list of int. I want the values extracted -

```
R

xyz

Y

abc

lmn

''
```

There has to be some method to convert it, but not sure which and how.

Now, I know I can get value just by;

```
cell_value = sh.cell_value(rowx=rx, colx=1)
```

but my program requires to collect rows first and then extract values from save row.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The row is a sequence of `Cell` instances, which have the attribute `value`.

```
for cell in row:
    cell_value = cell.value
    # etc
```

I am not sure why you want to do it this way - the reference to collecting rows first seems odd to me, given that you can get the rows directly from the worksheet.

Comment: The reason I need to do this way is because, program needs to get only certain rows selectively and then process the cell value of those selected rows. As it is large database, it needs to do this way rather than go for each row and cell in one phase. -But your solution worked! Thanks!

Comment: If my answer solved your problem, you may wish to accept it as described here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235 . That does two things. It lets everyone know your issue has been resolved, and it gives the person that helps you credit for the answer.